# Python dataframe get only the last list in json dumps

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm extracting excel file with multiple sheet, using for loop to read the Sheet name and values per sheet's. I'm satisfied with the value output inside the DataFrame.

But every sheet's my code create dataframes until the last sheet since Im using forloop to read every sheets, my problem is how to merge or append the multiple dataframe generate the code into single dataFrame?

Dataframe data format like this:

```
[{"id":0,"ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet1","menu":"test","value":"none"},{"id":1,"ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet1"}]
[{"id":0,"ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet2","menu":"sample","value":23},{"id":1,"ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet2"}]
[{"id":0,"ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet3","menu":"test","value":998},{"id":1,"ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet3"}]
```

But the problem is when I use **pd.concat and to_list** to merge all  inside the dataframe not working so the output when I dump the list is only the last.

```
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('../Excel_07879_data.xls')
sheets = [sheet for sheet in xls_file.sheet_names]
for sheet_name in sheets:
      df = pd.read_excel('../Excel_07879_data.xls', sheet_name=sheet_name)
      head, tail = os.path.split("../Excel_07879_data.xls")
      split_path = tail.rsplit("-",2)[1]
      df = pd.concat([df])
      df.replace(" ", np.NaN, inplace=True)
      df = df.rename(columns={"Control":'menu'})
      df[['menu']]=df[['menu']].apply(lambda x : x.str.strip())
      df['menu'].str.replace(' ', '')
      def shift_null(arr):
            return [x for x in arr if x == x] + [np.nan for x in arr if x != x]
      df2 = df.T.apply(lambda arr: shift_null(arr)).T
      df2.insert(loc=0, column='id', value=np.arange(len(df2)))
      df2.insert(loc=1, column='ost', value=split_path)
      df2.insert(loc=2, column='Sheet', value=sheet_name)
      df2 = pd.DataFrame.to_json(df2, orient='records',force_ascii=True,index=True)
      print (df2)
      json_list= json.loads(df2)


with open('../json/07879.json', 'w') as json_file:
      json.dump(json_list, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

The dataFrame that I want is like this:

```
[{"id":0,""ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet1","menu":"test","value":"none"},{"id":1,""ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet1"},{"id":2,""ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet2","menu":"sample","value":23"},{"id":3,""ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet2"},{"id":4,""ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet3","menu":"test","value":"998"},{"id":5,""ost":07879,"sheet":"sheet3"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, I think there is a problem in the use of "", second of all, in Python 3, leading zeros are not allowed on numbers. and if you fix these two, you can use the following to create a dataframe from all your data and change it back to the list of dicts you want as an output :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[{"id":0,"ost":"07879","sheet":"sheet1","menu":"test","value":"none"},{"id":1,"ost":"07879","sheet":"sheet1"}],
        [{"id":0,"ost":"07879","sheet":"sheet2","menu":"sample","value":"23"},{"id":0,"ost":"07879","sheet":"sheet2"}],
        [{"id":1,"ost":"07879","sheet":"sheet3","menu":"test","value":"998"},{"id":1,"ost":"07879","sheet":"sheet3"}]]

# get all the elements in one list
shape = (len(data[0])+1)*len(data[1])
elements = list(np.reshape(data, shape))

# convert to a single dataframe and make some changes on it
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(elements)
df.drop('id', axis='columns', inplace=True)

# reconvert to a list of dicts
df['id'] = df.index # this is added just to have the ids in the dicts
output = df.to_dict('records')
print(output)
```

output:

```
[{'ost': '07879', 'sheet': 'sheet1', 'menu': 'test', 'value': 'none', 'id': 0}, {'ost': '07879', 'sheet': 'sheet1', 'menu': nan, 'value': nan, 'id': 1}, {'ost': '07879', 'sheet': 'sheet2', 'menu': 'sample', 'value': '23', 'id': 2}, {'ost': '07879', 'sheet': 'sheet2', 'menu': nan, 'value': nan, 'id': 3}, {'ost': '07879', 'sheet': 'sheet3', 'menu': 'test', 'value': '998', 'id': 4}, {'ost': '07879', 'sheet': 'sheet3', 'menu': nan, 'value': nan, 'id': 5}]
```

by the way, the `to_dict` function offers also some other possibilities like `index` and so on